# How to obtain the given "analytical" solution to the 4th order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

The 4th order ODE is

$$(D^2-k^2)^2f=0, \qquad (1)$$

where $f=f(y)$, $D\equiv\frac{d}{dy}$, and $k$ is a constant. It is subject to the boundary conditions $f(0)=f'(0)=f(1)=0$.

A solution to (1) is given by,

$$f=a\left(\sinh k\eta+\frac{k\cosh k-\sinh k}{\sinh k}\eta\sinh k\eta-k\eta\cosh k\eta\right), \qquad (2)$$

where $a$ is constant, $\eta=\frac{y}{d}$ with $d$ a constant.

If I consider its characteristic equation:

$$r^4-2r^2k^2+k^4=0,$$

its solutions are $r_{1,2}=r_{3,4}=\pm k$, they then given a general solution

$$f=(\sinh ky+\cosh ky)(c_1+c_2y)+(\cosh ky-\sinh ky)(c_3+c_4y)$$

But I can not figure out how to obtain the solution (2)?

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ copper.hat thanks, the equation is how to obtain the solution (2) :P